# Null Safety alternative for cached network image

Tags: flutter, mobile

I creating an app in Flutter and I using the package cached_network_image in the code, but when I tried to debug the app the IDE show me an error message because the package don't support null safety. There are any alternative to this package with null safety? I don't want to disable null safety

Error message:

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:cached_network_image
```

pubspec.yaml declaration:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popular package `cached_network_image` migrated to null-safety in version 3. You should change your `pubspac.yaml` to use at least 3.0.0 (or use `3.2.0` at the time of writing this answer).

`cached_network_image: ^3.2.0`